# Fill a wireframe with a material?

Tags: modeling, materials

I would like to make a wireframe solid when using a specific Material and be a wireframe when not. Right now I have a normal Wireframe:[image]

And I would like to have it look filled with the same color, but a different material: [image]

This is just in edit mode but I would like to have it look like this. I found something about this already but since I'm fairly new to blender I don't understand what they do at all. [How to make a material switching from Wire frame material to surface material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102422/how-to-make-a-material-switching-from-wire-frame-material-to-surface-material)

I will keep on trying to understand what they are doing, but if there is a better way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using the **Wireframe modifier**. Instead use the **Wireframe input Node** to affect a **Mix Shader Node**

Here we have a Diffuse BSDF Node (Red) and a Transparent Shader mixed together. Without a Factor they will blend together to a pale Red.
With the Wireframe input as the factor only where the wireframe exists is Red, everywhere else is 100% transparent
[image: blender screenshot showing wireframe node setup]

As the geometry is not affected another material on the smae or duplicate object can be just solid.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, this works quite well but do you know if there is a way to reduce the lines it's creating? Doing this with a cube will not only show the edges but six extra diagonal edges like the ones you have in your sphere.

Comment: Add another Mix Shader and another Transparent BSDF Node before the Material Output. Use Input Node Geometry and feed Backfacing into the Factor.